# Obtener registros de varias tablas sin duplicados en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de traer los registros de la base de datos, tengo un sistema de inventario de algunos equipos tecnológicos, cada uno tiene un código de activo, pero un código de activo puede estar en varios equipos ya que un activo puede estar conformado de varios equipos por ejemplo: cpu, teclado, mouse, etc.

A su vez existen equipos que no tienen código de activo por lo que el código de los mismos es "N/A".

El problema es que al momento de extraer los datos de varias tablas, estoy teniendo demasiados duplicados.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select activo_fijo.id_activo,codigo_activo, codigo_ebye, 
(select marca_modelo_idcpu(cpu.id_cpu) as cpu), 
(select marca_modelo_idlaptop(laptop.id_laptop) as laptop),
cpu.id_cpu, laptop.id_laptop
from activo_fijo 
left join cpu on cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
left join laptop on laptop.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo
where (laptop.id_laptop IS NOT NULL or cpu.id_cpu IS NOT NULL)
```

Esto me devuelve los siguientes resultados:

[image: Resultado 1]

[image: Resultado 2]

[image: Resultado 3]

Como se puede ver se estan repitiendo los registros n veces por cada cpu con codigo "N/A" y n veces por cada laptop con codigo "N/A"

He intentado también:

```
select activo_fijo.id_activo,codigo_activo, codigo_ebye, 
(select marca_modelo_idcpu(cpu.id_cpu) as cpu), 
(select marca_modelo_idlaptop(laptop.id_laptop) as laptop),
cpu.id_cpu, laptop.id_laptop
from activo_fijo 
full outer join cpu on cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
full outerjoin laptop on laptop.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo
where (laptop.id_laptop IS NULL or cpu.id_cpu IS NULL)
```

Pero esa consulta me devuelve todos los cpu y laptop que no tienen codigo "N/A", por lo que se pierden equipos.

**¿Como podría eliminar esos duplicados?. Sin perder datos.**

El esquema de la base de datos es el siguiente:

[image: Esquema]

**EDIT LO QUE QUIERO OBTENER**

Esto es lo que obtengo actualmente:

[image: Actual]

Esto es lo que espero obtener:

[image: Esperado]

Es decir que se listen los 347 cpus, luego las laptops, y los demás equipos, pero sin que se repitan por ejemplo el cpu 346 con los ids de laptops.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el resultado esperado, ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: Estas intentando relacionar tablas a través de una clave primaria vacía. No es que pierdas equipos, es que no están bien relacionados. O desparecen del resultado final o aparecen tantas veces como combinaciones posible hay entre activos-cpus y activos-laptops. Otras solución es crear una `UNION` de dos selects, pero faltaría saber qué esperas obtener como salida.

Comment: @ChemaCortes, lo que espero como salida, son todos los equipos, pero separados, es decir en la tabla cpu tengo 347 equipos, y en la tabla laptops tengo 101, lo que deberia darme 448 equipos en total,  sin embargo me arrojan 1007 registros, ahora hago una imagen mas explicativa.

Comment: @ChemaCortes acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: Será que estoy viendo mal o no está la tabla laptop en el esquema? O esa información es generada con una función?

Comment: @Shaz tienes razon me he confundido de imagen, ahora ya puse la correcta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que deseas manejar de forma independiente las columnas de id_laptop e id_cpu, una forma sencilla de solucionarlo es con UNION y agregando una columna 'falsa' con valor null a cada consulta:

```
SELECT activo_fijo.id_activo, codigo_activo, codigo_ebye, 
(select marca_modelo_idcpu(cpu.id_cpu) as cpu), 
(select marca_modelo_idlaptop(laptop.id_laptop) as laptop),
cpu.id_cpu, null AS laptop.id_laptop
FROM activo_fijo 
LEFT JOIN cpu on cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
WHERE cpu.id_cpu IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT activo_fijo.id_activo, codigo_activo, codigo_ebye, 
(select marca_modelo_idcpu(cpu.id_cpu) as cpu), 
(select marca_modelo_idlaptop(laptop.id_laptop) as laptop),
null AS cpu.id_cpu, laptop.id_laptop
FROM activo_fijo 
LEFT JOIN laptop on laptop.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo
WHERE laptop.id_laptop IS NOT NULL
```

Si no se define la columna 'falsa', quedarían solo 6 columnas y los valores de id_cpu e id_laptop estarían en ella (sin duplicados).

Comment: Gracias @Shaz, funcionó correctamente, una pregunta más, si quisiera unir otra tabla como impresora, sería de la misma forma usando una columna falsa?

Comment: Sí, exacto, otra consulta y otra columna en todas las consultas, aunque UNION puede ser un poco pesado según la cantidad de elementos, pero no creo que sea el caso.